# DB2-Express-C and Postgresql using raw harddrive as datastore

Tags: postgresql, hard-drive, solaris, db2

I have a system running Solaris with 2 harddrives. One holding the OS and the other unpartitioned. I was thinking about using the second as database space.

My question is, if it is possible to let DB2-Express-C or Postgresql use the second harddrive as datastore WITHOUT partitioning the drive with the OS, as raw datastore.

In my opinion it should be possible with Oracle DB but I like to try it with these free-of-charge products first. The free Oracle-DB has to many limitations.

Comment: I'm trying to use my second hard drive as db2 store. Can you help me figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for PgSQL, but DB2 can use a raw device as a container for a tablespace. However, fewer and fewer installations are using raw devices as IBM has minimized the performance impact of using pre-allocated storage on file systems (i.e., "DMS File"). Most DB2 DBAs will tell you that the overhead of managing raw devices for database storage easily outweighs any potential performance benefit.